# B-Tree database options

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, b-tree

I need to implement two b-tree indexes of two different pgsql tables, preferably in memory on the same box a python webserver process is running on (queries need to be as fast as possible). I was wondering the best way to implement this:

1. Index and maintain b-trees in memory within the process (manually with a python library)
2. Implement the index in a separate, in-memory database (redis, mongo, etc)
3. Use a graph database like neo4j or flock (an excuse to play with the new hotness)
4. Tweaking pgsql to do the indexes itself. (at the cost of degradation of performance for the other data residing in the database?)

My needs are, in order of importance:

- query speed
- nearest neighbor search*
- index size
- open source
- python bindings :)

Additional Notes: Trees can reach up to several thousand nodes at once, will have to endure high insert/deletion rate

*So if I search for 756.837, but only 755.928 and 757.113 exist, return either one depending on parameters

To be clear, this postgres database will be serving traditional webapp crud data, on top of the data being processed. I'm willing to add complexity to maintain performance for the webapp data.

Comment: ..what about things like elasticsearch/solr? (but it might be an overkill if you don't need things like full-text search, etc.)

Comment: @redShadow probably overkill, as I'm merely indexing a range of objects by their associated numerical value

Comment: How much data are you talking about? With sufficient RAM, postgres will put the whole database in memory. Given the robustness of postgres, it seems like it would be harder to build and maintain a separate solution than just letting the engine do it for you.

Comment: @thisfeller probably no more than a gigabyte, maybe two at the max. I've considered that, however I already have indexes on some web app tables, and I'd _really_ rather not sacrifice that performance gain. A fast index for my data processing is worthless if it takes longer to retrieve a user's profile than to process the user's data.

Comment: @thisfeller additionally, looking into it more, I would have to `REINDEX` concurrently and very often. Unfortunately I think I'm going to have to go with something more arcane

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to see how far you can push the PostgreSQL indexes to do what you want.  Typical btree indexes are fast but they don't have a lot of features.  In particular, they aren't gong to give knn searches very well.  Depending on what you need, you might want to change your indexes from Btree to GiST.  GiST provides KNN searching (assuming your data types support this!) and allows you to do a lot of the rest of what you are looking for.  The downside is that depending on your data types you may end up needing to do some programming to get proper support for some data types.

GiST provides a greater number of search options than standard btree indexes, but they are also a bit slower to query.  The major advantage however is that they do support much higher insert/update rates than GIN indexes, and they support knn searches too.

If that does not work for you....  you may want to implement something else in memory, perhaps using an in-memory cache (like memcached) or even just plain old Sys V IPC and a separate process.  Be careful about concurrent access to memory though!